# How to resolve compiler warning 'implicit declaration of function memset'

Tags: c++, c

My c code uses 'memset' and 'close'.
And I have added:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <glib.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

But I still get these warnings:

```
main.c:259: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘memset’
main.c:259: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘memset’
main.c:268: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘close’
main.c:259: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘close’
```

Can you please tell me how can I resolve these warnings?

Thank you.

Answer (score 78):

You need:

```
#include <string.h> /* memset */
#include <unistd.h> /* close */
```

in your code.

References: POSIX for [`close`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/close.html), the C standard for `memset`.

Comment: Yeah, initially I had just seen the title and the first part of the warnings.  Updated.

Comment: +1 for telling the questioner where to find the information.  @OP: Don't guess, look it up!

Comment: Including <string.h> also solved my problem of incompatible implicit declaration warning when it comes to memcpy in GCC 4.8 on Windows.

Comment: @PiotrLopusiewicz yes, `memcpy()` is also declared in `string.h`: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/memcpy.html.

Comment: Right, this is indeed in standard. I was taken aback because Visual Studio compiler doesn't produce this warning.

Comment: @PiotrLopusiewicz I have no experience with Visual Studio.  With gcc, one has to enable warnings to get it to warn about certain kinds of warnings, so maybe there is a way to enable warnings in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 30):

A good way to findout what header file you are missing:

```
 man <section> <function call>
```

To find out the section use:

```
apropos <function call>
```

Example:

```
 man 3 memset
 man 2 send
```

Edit in response to James Morris:

- Section | Description
- 1    General commands
- 2    System calls
- 3    C library functions
- 4    Special files (usually devices,
  those found in /dev) and drivers
- 5    File formats and conventions
- 6    Games and screensavers
- 7    Miscellanea
- 8    System administration commands and
  daemons

Source: [Wikipedia Man Page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_page#Manual_sections)

Comment: Maybe explain why section 3 and section 2?

Comment: +1 for teaching by giving us a general solution rather than just giving the solution

Answer (score 16):

`memset` requires you to import the header `string.h` file. So just add the following header

```
#include <string.h>
...
```

Answer (score 5):

Try to add next define at start of your .c file:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
```

It helped me with pipe2 function.

Answer (score -1):

Old question but I had similar issue and I solved it by adding

```
extern void* memset(void*, int, size_t);
```

or just

```
extern void* memset();
```

at the top of translation unit ( *.c file ).

Comment: No, you have to `#include <string.h>` to declare `memset(3)`.

Comment: You *can* legally declare library functions yourself (that's what the standard headers do, after all) but there's no good reason to do so.

Comment: Btw, memset, memcpy, etc. are not always library functions. They can be a compiler's built-in functions. For example, I have no header "string.h" in SDK for my embedded system. So, suppressing the warning is the only way to clean build log.