# Need to get rid of the memset warning

Tags: c, warnings, memset

If I compile the below code I am getting a warning like this :

warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function memset [enabled by default]

```
void transform(int **a, int m, int n)
{
    int *row = malloc(m*sizeof(int));
    int *col = malloc(n*sizeof(int));
    memset(row, 0, sizeof(row));
    memset(col, 0, sizeof(col));
    [...]
```

Comment: `sizeof(row)` is whatever pointer size is on your platform. I.e. 4 in 32 bit env.. more correct thing would be `memset (raw, 0, m*sizeof(int))` - just a note :)

Comment: A `p=malloc(x*y)` followed by a `memset(p,0,x*y)` is the same as one call to `p=calloc(x,y)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compiler error: memset was not declared in this scope](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505365/compiler-error-memset-was-not-declared-in-this-scope). Actually, I meant [How to resolve compiler warning implicit declaration of function memset](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2144617/how-to-resolve-compiler-warning-implicit-declaration-of-function-memset).

Answer (score 7):

When in doubt, look at the man page:

```
$ man memset

MEMSET(3)                BSD Library Functions Manual                MEMSET(3)

NAME
     memset -- fill a byte string with a byte value

LIBRARY
     Standard C Library (libc, -lc)

SYNOPSIS
     #include <string.h>
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This tells you that you need `#include <string.h>` in order for the compiler to see the function prototype for `memset`.

Note also that you have a bug in your code - you need to change:

```
memset(row, 0, sizeof(row));
memset(col, 0, sizeof(col));
```

to:

```
memset(row, 0, m * sizeof(*m));
memset(col, 0, n * sizeof(*n));
```